# MS SQL Count number of cases which satisfy same condition as case in last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, conditional-statements

I would like to generate a column in SQL "PriorityCountInLast7Days" that counts the number of cases where the priority is the same as in that case. How do I do this in SQL?

For each Emp1, count the number of priorityinthelast7days = priorityatcurrentdate to generate PriorityCountinLast7days. Case is just a unique identifier of each row.

```
+------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|    Date    | Emp1 | Priority | PriorityCountinLast7days |
+------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| 2018-06-01 | A    |        0 |                        0 |
| 2018-06-03 | A    |        0 |                        1 |
| 2018-06-03 | A    |        0 |                        2 |
| 2018-06-03 | A    |        1 |                        1 |
| 2018-06-03 | A    |        2 |                        1 |
| 2018-06-04 | A    |        0 |                        3 |
| 2018-06-01 | B    |        0 |                        1 |
| 2018-06-02 | B    |        0 |                        2 |
| 2018-06-03 | B    |        0 |                        3 |
+------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Last seven days from now or from the `date` in the current row? And is `case` unique? And should the case of the current row be counted also? The rows for `'A4'` and `'A5'`suggest yes, the rows for `'A1'``, `'A2'` and `A3'` don't.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited!

Comment: @stickybbit yes case should be unique to each row.

Comment: Well, you just edited the problem and removed the [Case] field, which you said uniquely identified the row (like a primary key).  Now my answer appears irrelevant. 
 Not sure why you would remove that because now the data structure is not even in First Normal Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cross apply a subquery, that gets the count for cases of the same employee with the same priority from the last seven days relative to the day of the current row.

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.emp1,
       t1.[case],
       t1.priority,
       x.c prioritycountinlast7days
       FROM elbat t1
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT count(*) c
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.emp = t1.emp
                                      AND t2.priority = t1.priority
                                      AND t2.date >= dateadd(day, -7, t1.date)
                                      AND t2.date <= t1.date) x;
```

I still don't know, if the current case should be counted or not. As more of the sample data suggests yes, I wrote it that way. If it shouldn't be counted, add `AND t2.case <> t1.case` to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to re-query the table for a count.  The only hard part is the filters used to apply the count.  The output in this example differs from your expected output in the question, but at first glance I'm not sure how you determined your expected output given the rules of the algorithm.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Date date, Emp1 char(1), [Case] char(2), Priority int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 ('2018-06-01', 'A', 'A1', 0) 
,('2018-06-03', 'A', 'A2', 0)
,('2018-06-03', 'A', 'A3', 0)
,('2018-06-03', 'A', 'A4', 1)
,('2018-06-03', 'A', 'A5', 2)
,('2018-06-04', 'A', 'A6', 0)
,('2018-06-01', 'B', 'B1', 0)
,('2018-06-02', 'B', 'B2', 0)
,('2018-06-03', 'B', 'B3', 0) 

SELECT * 
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM @temp T2
         WHERE T2.Emp1 = T1.Emp1
           AND T2.[Date] <= DATEADD(DAY, 7, T1.[Date])
           AND T2.Priority = T1.Priority
           AND T2.[Case] < T1.[Case]

       ) AS [PriorityCountinLast7days]
  FROM @temp T1
```

Produces output:

```
Date        Emp1    Case    Priority    PriorityCountinLast7days
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-06-01  A       A1      0           0
2018-06-03  A       A2      0           1
2018-06-03  A       A3      0           2
2018-06-03  A       A4      1           0
2018-06-03  A       A5      2           0
2018-06-04  A       A6      0           3
2018-06-01  B       B1      0           0
2018-06-02  B       B2      0           1
2018-06-03  B       B3      0           2
```